# Как навесить событие onClick на пункт контекстного меню контрола DataGrid?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

В сетку грузится таблица из базы данных. Добавил в коллекцию Items контекстного меню сетки пару позиций. Но не пойму как добавить событие именно на этот пункт меню. Нашел только событие у самого меню, куда можно навесить обработчик клика:

```
this.cmGridMenu.ItemClicked += new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemClickedEventHandler(this.cmGridMenu_ItemClicked);
```

Окей, думаю, пусть все обрабатываются здесь. Но тогда как их отличить между собой? Какое поле можно воспринимать как индекс? Сейчас там почти пусто:

```
private void cmGridMenu_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e) {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi, stackoverflow!");
    }
```

Comment: добавьте код обработчика!

Comment: Добавил код, но он все-равно пустой.

Comment: sender приводишь к cmGridMenu.Item, и получаешь все данные о том где как и когда нажато меню.

Comment: Но ведь sender - это есть всё stripMenu целиком? Получается преобразовать в меню, но не в конкретный элемент: `Console.WriteLine(((ContextMenuStrip)sender).Items.Count);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Другой, более простой ответ. В целом, это я и надеялся услышать. Всё, что нужно было изменить в коде из вопроса, это использовать аргумент вызова обработчика, сравнивая его с именами, которые принадлежат элементам нашего меню (поле name у каждого элемента).

```
private void cmGridMenu_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e) {
        if (e.ClickedItem == tsmRestartChunkStep) {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi, stackoverflow!");
        } else if (e.ClickedItem == stepChangeStatusSucceeded){
            Console.WriteLine("How you doing?");
        }
    }
```

Comment: @VladimirT зацени. Оказывается, всё было просто как пять компеек, а мы фантазируем сидим :)

Comment: как задан вопрос, так его и откомментировал :)

Answer (score 0):

Не нашел как добраться к нужному событию из визуального интерфейса студии, но я сделал так:

1. Визуальными средствами создал коллекцию элементов контекстного
   меню.
2. Нашел все нужные элементы в коде дизайнера формы
   (MainForm.Designer.cs) по их именам.
3. Добавил всем обработчик с одной и той же функцией.

Фрагмент кода MainForm.Designer.cs

```
 this.tsChangeBatchStatusInProgress.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.cmGridMenuItem_Clicked);
 ...
 this.tsChangeBatchStatusCanceled.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.cmGridMenuItem_Clicked);
 ...
 this.tsChangeBatchStatusStopped.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.cmGridMenuItem_Clicked);
```

4. В теле обработчика смотрю на имя отправителя.

*Если есть более разумный способ (например, можно навесить обработчик на само меню и получать имя кликнутого элемента из sender'a), то буду рад услышать.*

```
switch (((ToolStripItem)sender).Name)
        {
            case "tsChangeBatchStatusInProgress": Console.WriteLine("Пачку берем в работу"); break;
            case "tsChangeBatchStatusCanceled": Console.WriteLine("Пачку отменяем"); break;
            case "tsChangeBatchStatusStopped": Console.WriteLine("Пачку приостанавливаем"); break;
        }
```

Comment: т.е я оказался прав :)

Comment: Ну не совсем. Нельзя (похоже) контекстное мени преобразовать к элементу как вы предлагали. Собственно, суть вопроса и была в том, как найти где цепляться к элементу, а не к меню (или как получить индекс нажатого, если вешаться на меню). На меню я повесился, но индексов никаких не нашел. Тогда полез руками добавляться в дезигнера на элементы.

Comment: а это `(ToolStripItem)sender` - что по вашему?

Comment: тут sender - это не тот sender, что в вопросе :) Этот можно преобразовать. Там его звали cmGridMenu - меню, а здесь tsChangeBatchStatusInProgress - элемент меню. Хотя доступа через визуал я так и не нашел. Но самое прикольное, что я по ходу еще один способ нащупал, где действительно в аргументах можно найти e.ClickedItem. Это более удобный способ (не нужно вешать на элементы обработчики).

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю ещё вариант. В окне дизайнера в верхней части окна *Свойства* находится выпадающий список со всеми компонентами на форме. Выбираете нужный ToolStripMenuItem, открываете вкладку *События* (значок молнии). Выбираете нужное событие, двойной щелчок ЛКМ, и можно писать обработчик.

Также выделить нужный компонент можно найдя его в окне *Структура документа*